# RAII with Exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, cout, raii

I've read about RAII a bit in the last few days and I always thought that I understood it.
So I just wanted to write a little program that has an Object that handles a file and wanted to try RAII with throwing an exception. Here is what I did:

```
using namespace std;

class FileHandler{
    FILE* file;
public:
    FileHandler(const string &s, const char *r){
        cout << "opened file";
        file = fopen(s.c_str(), r);
        fputs("test", file);
    }
    ~FileHandler(){
        cout << "closed file";
        fclose(file);
    }
};

#include "FileHandler.h"
#include <stdexcept>

int main() {
    FileHandler fileHandler("test.txt", "w");
    throw std::invalid_argument("why does this not work?");

}
```

From what I know about RAII the Destructor of FileHandler should be called and I should have an output on my console but somehow I don't get any output except the output for the exception. Does the exception output override my cout output or is my understanding of RAII wrong.
I wanted to use this code to demonstrate to somebody else how RAII works, which is not really helpfull when I dont have the expected console output.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: RAII only work with exceptions if you handle those exceptions.  In your case you do not, so once the exception causes `main` to exit, `std::abort` is called and the program is immediately terminated.  No stack unwinding happens and that means your object is not destroyed.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's implementation-defined if stack unwinding happens here or not.

Comment: @DerWolferl `catch` the exception, then the destructor will be called. Also, I'm not sure if it's intentional or not (for brevity), but your code doesn't follow [the rule of three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you, that makes sense, so RAII only helps me in a way, that I dont have to remeber to write fclose() in every catch-Block where I use my File resource?

Comment: Yes, what else could it do?